# Etherscan.io websocket sending old transactions

Tags: javascript, websocket, ethereum

looking to get the most recent transactions from an address using the etherscan websocket api. For some reason the websocket is sending me transactions that are 2-3 hours old.

For instance:

```
// Subscribing to binance address (as its an address with a lot of transactions):
socketData.ether.send(JSON.stringify({"event": "txlist", "address": "0x3f5CE5FBFe3E9af3971dD833D26bA9b5C936f0bE"}))
```

returns old transactions.

I'm looking for new transactions that are confirmed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like this websocket just sends transactions that are around 1.5 to 3 hours old. huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this websocket just sends transactions that are around 1.5 to 3 hours old. huh. May have something to do with the ETH network being backed up. Pls scale, vitalik ;)